# Why htmlparse and soupselect works for ios and fails to android on titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

```
var htmlparser = require('/htmlparser');
var select = require('/soupselect').select;
var handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler(function(err, dom) { ... }
```

On iOS it is ok, but when I simulated on Android, I got this message error

[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,2113] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

It is an error with the lib or with commonjs?

The code of htmlparser and soupselect i got from here : https://gist.github.com/bob-sims/4406293

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct on Android? Have you tried without the "/" in front of the name?

Comment: Where the commons library lives on Android? same the iOS at /lib ?
Look that my question is from Titanium Framework Env

Comment: I know, but paths are different depending on the platform. Try it.

Comment: Humm.. i tried now without the slash, however doesn't work :(
I think that it is a problem with common js, because this link:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130243/commonjs--require---problems-with-new-operator-works-on-ios-fails-on-android